# net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS if I want to open website in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

When I try to open a washington post [article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/acts-of-faith/wp/2017/06/30/trump-promised-to-destroy-the-johnson-amendment-congress-is-targeting-it-now/) in puppeteer, I get error:

**Error: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

```
internal/process/warning.js:27 (node:70458) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS at https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/acts-of-faith/wp/2017/06/30/trump-promised-to-destroy-the-johnson-amendment-congress-is-targeting-it-now/
    at navigate (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:121:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.goto (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:674:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
    at .../app.js:255:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

**app.js**

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/acts-of-faith/wp/2017/06/30/trump-promised-to-destroy-the-johnson-amendment-congress-is-targeting-it-now/');

  const html = await page.content()
  console.log(html)
  await browser.close()
})()
```

I tried to abort navigation redirects based on [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1132#issuecomment-393724933), but then I get **Error: net::ERR_FAILED**

```
internal/process/warning.js:27 (node:70488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: net::ERR_FAILED at https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/acts-of-faith/wp/2017/06/30/trump-promised-to-destroy-the-johnson-amendment-congress-is-targeting-it-now/
    at navigate (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:121:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.goto (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:674:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
    at .../app.js:247:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

Comment: Try using [this url](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/acts-of-faith/wp/2017/06/30/trump-promised-to-destroy-the-johnson-amendment-congress-is-targeting-it-now/?noredirect=on) It's where I get redirected in incognito mode.

Comment: @pguardiario it didn't change anything

Comment: You might just want to post an issue in the github page, this sounds like a bug.

Comment: @pguardiario good idea, I am about to do that

Comment: This script is working completely fine for me, try switching to a different network, it may be possible that web server is blocking your IP.

Comment: This code is working for me

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try the following:

1. Try seeing what is going on on the [redirectChain](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#requestredirectchain).
2. Check the `response.status()` to see if it returns a redirect code (`3xx`).
3. Try faking some headers inside your request. Some bigger sites usually prevents APIs from digging around. Using `User-Agent` can help with this.

Comment: #1 and 2 didn't work for me, because the error occurs on the "const response = await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});" line. Adding the chain stuff after that line as the linked page suggests is too late, because the error has already occurred.

Comment: It turns out that my issue was the following: I work in multiple projects that uses the same port over the development environment. The reason was that one of those projects was programmed to use a 304 status code. This response is saved on the cache, causing the other projects to attempt a redirect earlier on.